# Copy file from ehternet-connected FTP - no internet

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

I have a device that stores data in an FTP-accessible folder. I can connect to it through windows (ftp:10.19.1.101) and map drive to it (C:\Users#ME#\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\MyDevice). There are no usernames or passwords - if the device is attached, you have access.
i can click and drag the file in Windows. I want to automate that in VBA so I can process the file. 
The single file is located at the root (ftp://10.19.1.101/fs.log), and I want to copy it to a location on my C drive to process it in Excel. I've tried for hours using code snips found here to no avail. I don't access the internet to get it, and I think that might be the problem, since 99% of FTP activity is that way.

FileCopy doesn't work either.

Any help appreciated

Comment: I discovered that I was entering the path wrong for connecting. I am an idiot. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access it and map it to a drive, open up a cmd then type 'net use' and hit enter (when it's plugged in and mapped to a drive). You should then have the long location used by windows which you can use in your procedures to play around with the file?

HTH